# New to Rails -- Webrat methods not working in integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rack, testunit, webrat

I have a Gemfile:

```
        source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
    gem 'omniauth'
    gem 'omniauth-facebook'

    gem 'thin'
    # Bundle edge Rails instead:
    # gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

    gem 'pg'

    gem 'devise'
    gem 'rmagick'


    # Because rails_admin_jcrop autoload modules by checking plugins you use, it's
    # recommended to require it explictly before rails_admin_jcrop
    # e.g. if you use carrierwave
    gem 'carrierwave', :require => 'carrierwave'

    # Gems used only for assets and not required
    # in production environments by default.
    group :assets do
      gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
      gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

      gem 'compass-rails'
      gem 'zurb-foundation'

      # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
      # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

      gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    end

    group :test do
      gem 'webrat', '>=0.7.2.pre', :git => 'http://github.com/kalv/webrat.git' 
      gem "database_cleaner"
    end

    gem 'jquery-rails'

    # To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
    # gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

    # To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
    # gem 'jbuilder'

    # Use unicorn as the app server
    # gem 'unicorn'

    # Deploy with Capistrano
    # gem 'capistrano'

    # To use debugger
    # gem 'debugger'
    gem 'therubyracer'
```

And test_helper.rb:

```
 

        ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
    require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
    require 'rails/test_help'
    # require "webrat"


    Webrat.configure do |config|
      config.mode = :rails
    end


    class ActiveSupport::TestCase
      # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.
      #
      # Note: You'll currently still have to declare fixtures explicitly in integration tests
      # -- they do not yet inherit this setting
      fixtures :all
    #   include Webrat
      include Webrat::Methods
      include Webrat::Matchers
      # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
    end

    class ActionController::TestCase
      include Devise::TestHelpers
    end
```

My test is:

```
 

        require 'test_helper'

    class UserSignupTest  user.first_name
        fill_in "user_last_name", :with => user.last_name
        fill_in "user_username", :with => user.username
        fill_in "user_email", :with => user.email
        fill_in "user_password", :with => user.password
        fill_in "user_password_confirmation", :with => user.password_confirmation
        choose("user_sex_male") 
        click("commit")
      end

    end
```

But I have the following errors when I try to use the 'click' method:

```
  

         1) Error:
    test_sign_up_flow(UserSignupTest):
    NoMethodError: undefined method `click' for #
```

Do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong? I just bundle installed and thought it should work. The methods preceding the 'click' method seem to work somehow.

Comment: Can you try including the test_helper as a file? i.e. `require './test_helper.rb'` if test_helper.rb is in the same directory.

Comment: If I write:  

 require './test_helper' 

I get:   
 `require': cannot load such file -- ./test_helper (LoadError)

Not sure I understand.

Comment: In that case, try something like this - `require File.expand_path('./test_helper.rb', __FILE__)`. Also, check if test_helper and the test are in the same location. Otherwise you need to manipulate this code to have the right relative path.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll check that in the morning. I really don't get why the fill_in methods work but click doesn't.

Comment: Is 'Commit' a button? In that case you should try using `click_button`, without above changes I recommended.

Comment: Yeah it is. It's hard to find documentation for Webrat (or I just am not good at it). I switched to capybara and found that out and am all good. Appreciate the help =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the comments are getting chatty, I am posting this as an answer.

[Webrat Resources and references](https://github.com/brynary/webrat#webrat-).

In your case, since 'Commit' is a button, you need to use

```
click_button("commit")
```

instead of

```
click("commit")
```

If it were a link, you can use

```
click_link("commit")
```

Comment: just cause this has gotten chatty -- =] -- mind if i ask a somewhat random question? i always need to look things up but i sometimes find people who answer their own questions with code that is pretty involved with the gems and frameworks used. i'm new to programming -- do you have any advice for me if i want to reach that level of proficiency?

Comment: @wjandali - Your original question was easier to answer :P. I believe everyone needs to look things up, its just that over time two things happen - you encounter similar problems or, you learn how to look things up (hint - starts with 'g'). As long as you are persistent enough, I think the problems would get solved.